# Path based extensibility model not working with dotnet-cli on Mac

Tags: .net, dotnet-cli

I tried creating a custom command that could be executed using `dotnet` driver. Followed the steps mentioned in the documentation.

1. Created a command with the name `dotnet-demo`
2. Added basic `echo "Welcome to Custom Command"` script inside the command
3. Enabled execution on this file using `chmod +x dotnet-demo`
4. Added this script to the path by enabling symlink using `ln -s dotnet-demo /usr/local/bin`
5. Running the command using `dotnet demo` is not giving any errors. Neither it produces any output.

Not able figure out, what I am missing here ?

Comment: Could you link to the documentation that you followed?

Comment: i followed the steps mentioned at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/extensibility

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the symbolic link creation step. Upon using the full path of the command, things started working fine. i.e, `ln -s <full-path>/dotnet-demo /usr/local/bin/dotnet-demo` did the magic. Now running the command `dotnet demo` produces the expected output